# Tomcat not executing the correct realm

Tags: java, xml, tomcat, context.xml

I am working on a tomcat 7 webapp that I recently inherited. We are working on migrating from Tomcat 5.5.

The webapp uses a tomcat realm to handle a combination of ldap/sql authentication.

When I define my context.xml as follows

```
<Context docBase="*******" reloadable="false">
    <Realm className="com.******.tomcat.auth.LdapSqlRealm"
       ****
     />
    <Resource name="jdbc/*****"
      auth="Container"
      type="javax.sql.DataSource"
      factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
      testWhileIdle="true"
      testOnBorrow="true"
      testOnReturn="false"
      validationQuery="SELECT 1"
      validationInterval="30000"
      timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="60000"
      maxActive="15"
      maxIdle="15"
      maxWait="30000"
      initialSize="10"
      removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
      removeAbandoned="true"
      logAbandoned="true"
      minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="60000"
      numTestsPerEvictionRun="2"
      jmxEnabled="true"
      jdbcInterceptors="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;
        org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer"
      username="*****"
      password="*****"
      driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
      url="*****"
    /></Context>
```

I can see my realm initializing in the logs, but when I go to authenticate (using basic) it doesn't use my realm.

If I define the realm in the server.xml file it works just fine.

Any thoughts on why I can't define it in the context.xml.

Our context.xml file is actually located in cont/Catalina/localhost/*****.xml

I have tried starting from scratch with simple realms, or extensions of RealmBase and they all do the same thing.

Thanks,
Travis

Comment: When you define your <realm> in your context.xml file instead of in server.xml, what happens? Is it the same as if no realm was defined at all?

Comment: When I define the realm in the context (versus server.xml) I don't see anything get logged from my realm. However it does show that it is calling functions in RealmBase. The realm that I inherited does extend RealmBase. So it looks like it calls only the base code, not my extensions.

Comment: Your realm implementation is named "com.******.tomcat.auth.LdapSqlRealm". Where is the library that contains this class? Is it there in your server any other class with the same name+package?

Comment: It is a custom library that is dropped into the lib folder in tomcat. I am a little confused by the second question, but its separate from the app (different project/jar)

Comment: That is quite OK. Have you tried -as proof of concept- to develop a single custom realm and deploy it over an _empty_ application? (I mean: a web application with no code; just a dummy HTML for testing).

Comment: I can try that. I tried a custom realm with the current web app, but I can try it with a new one.

Comment: Fine. And it will be even better if you use a "virgin", out-of-the-box Tomcat installation.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that I had an extra `<Context />` tag in my `<Host />` tag in my server.xml which was messing up my context.xml file.

Little Santi tipped me off by suggesting a vanilla build of tomcat, which I didn't end up doing, but I did a compare of server.xml from the two and spotted the issue right away. Wish I had thought of it sooner.

Comment: Good for you! Congratulations.